# Getting zenith angle with pv.solarposition.spa_python

Tags: pvlib

I'm trying to get the zenith angle with: `pv.solarposition.spa_python(date_range, latitude, longitude)` but some of the angles I get are above 90 degrees- why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Zenith angle > 90 means the sun is below the horizon.